# ASP.NET MVC 3 Web API - Securing with token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, oauth

I'm trying to find the simplest way of implementing token based authentication for a number of ASP.NET MVC actions.

The Api controllers sit alongside a web app, so I need to be able to specify which actions/controllers are subject to Api authentication.

I already have a membership provider that is used for forms authentication so I'd like to reuse this to validate the user and build the returned token.

I've read several articles on implementing OAuth, but most seem really complex.  I've seen several examples of using an API key, but I want to request a token and then pass it back as a parameter not necessarily as a value in the HTTP header.

Essentially process needs to be:

1. User requests token from auth action passing in username and
   password.
2. Service returns enc token
3. User passes enc token to future calls as a parameter to auth

What's the typical way this is done, does the client (say ajax call) need to compute a hash of the user name/pass in 1)? or plain text ok over TLS/SSL?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What are you concerned about with what you described?

The process you described seems viable.  Typically systems will have an expiration on how long the token will be valid for, after which they need to get a new token.  There are many variations for expiration though (fixed time, sliding time, etc..).

To your question regarding the username / password, the client shouldn't hash them.  Just make sure they are transmitted via a secure method (SSL).